Does anyone recognise this phantom 404 error when I build with base
Why am I seeing this phantom 404, when, in the network pane, all requests are 200 OK? My SPA seems to have loaded faultlessly and breakpoints show that my script bundle is executing as desired, before the 404 error appears on screen. This is extremely weird. Does anyone recognise this?
The site is a vite build of a React SPA, built with a base path, served with the http-server extension for visual studio code, but none of that should matter once all the requests have succeeded. If I build the same project without the base argument, it all works fine. But as I said, all requests are succeeding and all files are loaded.


What is "base path" in this context? The screenshot says there was an application error, not an HTTP-status error... what is that error, can you tell? Please [edit] to include clearer details and a complete [mcve] of the relevant code and configurations you are alluding to.

So "base" is the path from the root of the domain to the root of the site. Vite needs to know this, so it can glue it in front of the links on the index.html page. But react router also needs to know it, as I found out. It seems obvious, but it really stumped me for a while, because I had been trying to fix real 404 errors linked to the build.

If your app is not running at the root of the domain, react router also needs to know the base path. I'm using createBrowserRouter, called when my Index.html loads, and the location of Index.html determines the base to use, so I can just supply window.location.pathname in the options, as follows...
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Products />,
  }
  ...
],{basename: window.location.pathname});

This way, react router will just work, whether the site is running at the root of the domain or not.
